# Laravel : Upload multiple image but First image only uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am using Laravel 4.2 and I have this form to upload multiple images

the problem when I submit the form it returns to the view page and the first image only uploaded.

can anyone please review my code and correct my mistake

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'doAddProjectImage', 'files'=>'true', 'method'=>'PUT', 'class'=>'margin-top-30 width-100per pull-left')) }}
  {{ Form::file('img[]', array('class'=>'file', 'multiple'=>true)) }}
  {{ Form::submit('Add images to project', array('class'=>'btn-success btn pull-left')) }}
  {{ Form::hidden('pid', Session::get('insId')) }}
  {{ Form::close() }}
```

and this is my controller

```
public function doAddProjectImage()
    {
        $proId = Input::get('pid');

        $projectImages = new ProjectsImages();
        $files = Input::file('img');
        foreach($files as $file) {
            $destination_path = 'images/projects/';
            $filename = str_random(6) . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move($destination_path, $filename);

            $projectImages->image = $filename;
            $projectImages->image_id = $proId;
            $projectImages->save();
        }

        return Redirect::to('admin/view-project');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I found that `'multiple'=>true` was the mistake it should be `multiple`

so the input field will be

```
{{ Form::file('img[]', array('class'=>'file', 'multiple')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with my code

**Controller**

```
 public function img_upload($filename)
    {
        $photo = array('photo' => $filename);
        $destinationPath = 'uploads/multiple'; // upload path
        $original_filename = time().$filename->getClientOriginalName(); // getting image extension
        $extension = $filename->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
        //$fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image
        $filename->move($destinationPath, $original_filename); 
    }

    public function savemultiimage(Request $request)
    {   
        $files = $request->file('m_name');
        $file_count = count($request->file('m_name'));      
        foreach ($files as $file) {          
                $this->img_upload($file);
                $multi['m_name']=time().$file->getClientOriginalName(); 
                DB::table('multiimage')->insert($multi);
        }
        return redirect('/multifiles/gallery')->with('succ', 'Multiple image successfully inserted!');
    }
```

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'multifiles/savemultiimage','id'=>'multi_image','files'=>true)) !!}

    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputFile">Multi Images</label>
          <input type="file" id="m_name" name="m_name[]" multiple>          
        </div> 
    </div><!-- /.box-body -->

    <div class="box-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I think this Laravel 5 yes I using Laravel 4.2